# How to find match percentage in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I want the match percentage of string match with table field value.
Ex. In table student there is address field(this contain full address), i want to search in table student address is like "Mumbai" but i want in percentage of this match.

Comment: percentage on what basis?

Comment: `select from table_name where address LIKE '%mumbai%'`  you mean this?

Comment: see in my table student there are many address for each student. suppose i want to search like Mumbai then it will give me all record which contain address Mumbai but i want the percentage of that match  Ex. address- Sr.no20, Nerul,Mumbai and i search by Mumbai, I want then percentage of search match with field result

Answer (score 1):

If using native php without framework ..select from table_name where address like '%variable%'
Or if using framework you should check syntax for that framework ...for example in codeigniter 
$this->db->like(field_mame,'%'.variable.'%')

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(address_column like '%mumbai%' or null)*100/count(*) as percentage from your_table;
```

This will count addresses like mumbai , multiply it by 100 and divide it by total count.